# generating events in Unix/c/Python

Tags: python, c, unix

I want to write up a Program either in C / Python - Unix(Open SUSE) for the following:-

1) Report / alarm mechanism : wherin if some updatation has been done in particular folder,  or anything else changed at OS level, then it would raise an alarm or a signal should be sent to already executing program and would then do accordingly.

I read signal() seems to be a solution to my problem, but how can i use this user-defined signal to solve my purpose. Please help. Some resources would be good.

Or if any other technique is available kindly let me know.

Thanks

Comment: should be there a `2)` point ?

Comment: joaquin: [There is **no** point 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruces_sketch).

Comment: no point in saying this.

Answer (score 1):

Use libev, its easy to embed it into your application,, Using either C or Python.
http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html

and this is a refrence,, http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the right tool for your job is 
Pyinotify --

Project overview page is here: 
https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki

The URL for the code is just here, but it can be installed with Python's easy_install or pip:
https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

It is designed just for that: call a function on your running code whenever some monitored directory or file is modified in a linux system.

==edit==

sorry, Imissed the "anything else changed at OS level" part - but maybe that is just to broad for a single answer.
However, the one technology developed with Linux for notifying porograms of system-level events (like peripheral  and filesystem connect/disconnect, CPU state changes, and so on) is DBUS.

DBUS can be used from both C and Python - I had not used it, but inherit from KDE 3 era DCOP idea - DCOP used to be quite usable. You can see examples and instrucions on how o use DBUS here:

- http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings
- http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: PyInotify is only for file system events.